# Как не показывать запрос боту, при нажатии кнопки в Telegram боте на python/

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Не могу понять как сразу удалять текстовый запрос боту, то есть кнопка нажимается игроками постоянно и канал засоряется запросами (В данном примере запрос Биология). Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
elif message.text == 'Биология ⚧':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Новая биология ⚧: ' + random.choice(bio) + random.choice(bio2) + random.choice(bio3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
elif message.text == 'Биология ⚧':
      bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Новая биология ⚧: ' + random.choice(bio) + random.choice(bio2) + random.choice(bio3))
```